# Is is possible to filter the output of tail?

Tags: unix, tail

I'd like to tail a file but only output lines that have a certain string in them.  Is this possible?

Comment: If you are working with logs then use [lnav](https://lnav.org/) command

Answer (score 34, accepted):

use grep.  Its built just for that purpose.

To find lines from a tail of /var/log/syslog that have "cron" in them, just run:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep cron
```

And since it accepts anything over stdin, you can use it on the output of any other command as well, by piping in the same way as above (using the | symbol).

Comment: While this is essentially right, it's important to realize that `grep` will buffer when it is used non-interactively, such as when it is part of a longer pipeline. GNU grep 2.5.1 offers the `--line-buffered` option to work around this when eliminating grep from the pipeline isn't an option. (When I say grep will *buffer* I mean you won't see output until the buffer has reached something like 4k.)

Comment: To supplement previous comment, "tail -f" under modern Linux will work in a loop, waiting for more input in the syslog file. To have the command actually finish with the existin contents of the file, omit the -f switch: 

tail /var/log/syslog | grep cron

Answer (score 7):

```
tail -f /var/log/messages | grep "myfilterword"
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a couple other ideas, which while not as simple, may offer some interesting additional flexibility:

First, you can filter with awk instead of grep:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages | awk '/myfilterword/'
```

that works exactly the same as the example using `grep`.  You can expand on this by using the power of awk, for example:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages | \
awk '/myfilterword/ { for (i=6; i<=NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("\n")}'
```

which will print the 6th through the last field of the output (fields are whitespace separated)

Another similar idea is to use a perl one-liner:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages | perl -ne "/myfilterword/ and print"
```

that works exactly like `grep`.  Maybe you want a line number counter and just the 6th field?  How about this:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages | \ 
perl -lane "/myfilterword/ and printf \"%6d %s\n\",++\$a,\$F[6]"
```

Obviously all of these sorts of things can be done with other tools too, but I wanted to illustrate that there are some fun ways to use more general purpose languages like awk or perl here.

Comment: +1 great elaboration on how to expand further than grep!

Answer (score 2):

Another trick worth noting, if you have a CSV file with headers that you want to omit, e.g.:

```
% cat data.txt
fruit        dessert        calories
Apple        Pie            770
Banana       Pudding        625
Cherry       Cobbler        990
% tail -n +2 data.txt
Apple        Pie            770
Banana       Pudding        625
Cherry       Cobbler        990
```

It doesn't matter how long the input to `tail` is, the `+n -2` will omit the first line.